# How to make a row in a grid not appear if it's value is 0?

Tags: peoplesoft, peoplecode

I only have two fields in my grid. Just need the entire row to not appear, if the value in one of the fields is 0.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions for your need, but this one is working for me in a similar setup.

Following code is in the PostBuild event of the component:

```
Local Rowset &rs;
&rs = GetLevel0()(1).GetRowset(Scroll.MainRecordOfTheGrid);
&rs.Flush();
&rs.Select(Record.MainRecordOfTheGrid, "WHERE FieldA<>0 and FieldB<>0");
```